# Is Browser Finger Printing really Unique?

Tags: browser

Does the version of the browser play any role in identifying the browser's uniqueness? 
Is there any other way to identify users when there is a browser upgrade using finger-print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: It depends on how you implement browser fingerprinting.

Long answer: You could choose to include the browser version in the fingerprint, or you could leave it out. If your fingerprinting system just, for instance, uses a hash of the unaltered "user-agent" header to identify browsers, then **yes**, updates will change the fingerprint (at least in Chrome; I assume most, if not all, other browsers will be the same in this regard). You could probably use a regex to get rid of version numbers, but I don't know how easy this would be to do reliably, and that would make it less unique.

Browser fingerprinting is a balance between diversity and stability- the more information you include in the fingerprint, the more unique individual browsers will be, but the more likely they will be to change (i.e. when the user updates their browser). Keep in mind that factory-installed browsers are often identical between machines of the same model.

Comment: Apologies, let me re-phrase my question. If the version of the browser is changed does the finger print get changed? 
Is there a way we could avoid this?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I guess, we can omit the version number while we create the finger print.

Answer (score 1):

While, in fact, this is very similar to the existing and accepted answer, I'd like to add another view on this topic: You can actually omit the "browser" from "browser fingerprinting". The analogy still holds even for biometrics:

Upon each "creation" of a fingerprint, you might get slightly different outputs, just like different scans of the same finger will create different images. You're then deciding on how good a match must be in order to signal "identity". If you take too few features of the scanned fingerprint, you might be far from unique (e.g. generate *false positives*). If you take too many features into account, you might generate *false negatives*, e.g. assume that this is not the same finger/browser that you have seen before.

There is no wrong or right way to judge - you'll have to come up with a result that is tuned to your usecase. E.g., when I'm taking my notebook on the road, my screen resolution will be the native resolution of the display. When I'm in office, there's another monitor connected to it, changing the screen resolution. Occasionally I'm installing or updating a plugin. Or the browser. Or any other component in the system that might have an effect on the various browser fingerprinting methods out there.

And just as in real life, no matter how detailed your check is, you might find twins - legitimate unique fingerprints that refer to two different individuals/browsers.